# What's the solution for bidirectional Replication type on vertical filtered table(some of columns) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication, transactional-replication

Assume we have a table in two database instance like following:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentList
(
     StudentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     StudentName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
     StudentGrade int
)
```

We want to create a bidirectional replication between these two SQL Server 2008 instances on the first and second columns (vertical filtered) **without** removing the third column in the second table.

The peer-to-peer transactional and merge replication don't permit us for doing this.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Merge replication allows filtering the articles as well as **you can choose [CHECK/UNCHECK] which columns you want to be replicated**.

Try to avoid bi-directional transactional replication as this feature will be removed in next version : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx

Comment: That's true. but after adding subscription to created replication the replication removes filtered columns in subscription. I don't want this removing!!!

Comment: do you need StudentGrade column data to be replicated?

Comment: No I don't. I want to have same StudentID and StudentName and different StudentGrade in synchronized table rows !

Answer (score 1):

@mirza - The filtered column is being dropped at the Subscriber because you are initializing with a snapshot and the Merge Article property **@pre_creation_cmd** is set to **drop**.  To accomplish vertical filtering and not have the columns removed on initialization you will need to [initialize the Merge Subscription without a snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152488%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  This way the column(s) will not be dropped at the Subscriber.

Comment: Yes but it could get complicated especially if you're using parameterized filters.